# can alarmManager.set get for String

Tags: android, alarmmanager

```
 public String getCurrentTime(){
    Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.i("Calander getinstance",Calendar.getInstance()+"");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ");
    String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    return strDate;
}

public void alert()
{
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myReceiver.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);
      AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,Long.parseLong(getCurrentTime()), pendingIntent);
}
```

In getCurrentTime, It must be return String but

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,Long.parseLong(getCurrentTime()), pendingIntent); is only get for Long. Is that Another way. Help Plz.
```

Comment: why u want string dude

Comment: PHP returns "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format. String return. So, I change my current time into that format. If Alarm Manager only get Long , I'll be in a problem.

Comment: Sorry. I can't see your ans. Where's it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot parse the formated time back to long.You need to parse the string with your formatter again to get the time.

So Before setting your time to your alarmmanager you need create another SimpleDateFormat object.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ");
```

And now

```
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,(sdf.parse(getCurrentTime())).getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Ok, I see. Now, I'm trying.

Comment: And I have a question. Can I show notification when my app is totally closing.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public String getCurrentTime()
```

to

```
public long getCurrentTime()
```

and return `c.getTime().getTime()`. This will return the current time in `milliSeconds`. You can manipulate the `Calendar` instance to get your required time.

Comment: I wanna get "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format. So I can't change String to Long. So, Can I something change in alarm manager.

Comment: You will need to extend the `AlarmManager` class and do your own custom implementation but in the end the `AlarmManager` will only accept `long` value.

Comment: PHP returns "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format. String return. So, I change my current time into that format. If Alarm Manager only get Long , I'll be in a problem.

Comment: Parse the `String` you reecive from PHP with `SimpleDateFormat` which will return `Date` object and then use that object to get time in `milliSeconds`

Comment: How? Give a guide... please.

Comment: Check this out [Parse String to Date](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe write like this:

```
long triggerTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
```